# Comment décrire plusieurs homophones en un seul ?

Tags: orthographe, phonétique

Par exemple quel mot peut on placer à la fin de cette phrase ?

> Je mis un sceau dans un seau et emportai les deux …

Comment: S'ils n'étaient pas homophones, ajouterais-tu un mot ? Pourquoi le faire dans ce cas-ci donc ?

Comment: Ça me rappelle la blague: _un maigre sot monté sur un cheval porte dans un seau le sceau du roi. Le cheval fait un saut qui fait tomber... les trois...?_ La réponse est: _qui fait tomber l'étroit sot_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Le plus simple dans ce cas c'est de n'ajouter aucun mot, et d'utiliser « les deux » comme un pronom.

> J'ai mis un sceau dans un seau et j'ai emporté les deux.

Il n'y a aucune autre solution élégante, bien que *s(c)eaux* serait compris.

Comment: J'espérais une règle technique pour finir cette phrase.

Comment: Utiliser "les deux s(c)eaux", serait compris à l'écrit (à l'oral, cela pourrait porter à confusion...), et ce serait un jeu de mot. Si c'est un texte sérieux, ce n'est donc pas recommandé. Si le but est de faire un jeu de mot, ce serait par contre la tournure à privilégier.